# Body Style CSS not working

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I'm learning XHTML/HTML and CSS. Right now, my current CSS is not working and I don't know why. I have tried changing the color to teal, black, etc. And same for `background-color`, and still appears as this :

Image here:

[image]

The HTML is not written by me, it's taken from a book code snippet for testing.

Here's my [HTML](http://pastebin.com/rNaqZvAc).

(I couldn't get code snippets or the html snippet to work.)

Comment: replace “ character to "

Answer (score 3):

You should use `"` double or single `'` quotes for HTML attribute values, but not this `”` quotes.
Your working code with the example you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kx5Ju/).

Comment: You should always run your site through the W3C validator at http://validator.w3.org first.